# Cisco Switch vIOS-L2 in GNS3 and CCNA 200-301

Tags: switch, vlan, dhcp, gns3

I am reading a preparation book for the CCNA Test 200-301. Currently, I am reading a section about DHCP and VLAN interfaces in a switch. The book shows an example of configuring this.

```
switch# configure terminal
switch# interface vlan 1
switch# ip address dhcp
switch# no shutdown
switch# end
```

To practice, I am using GNS3 and vIOS-L2. However, when I try the subcommand `ip address dhcp`, I get the following message:

```
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

I think this happens because vIOS does not have this command due to the version. So, how can I configure this in vIOS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature is not available in the L2 version.   You need the L3 version.

Comment: Thank you. With your answer I tie up loose ends